# How to add correctly google_play-services

Tags: android, google-play-services

I have an android application that I have to run on my laptop (I didn't develop it). The thing is, first I had an error that said `Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found` so I fixed adding this to the build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.1.0'
    }
}
```

that works, then I go to compile the project and I have an error like this:

```
Project with path ':AppData:Local:Android:sdk:extras:google:google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib' could not be found in root project 'Aplicacion'.
```

in the file *build.gradle* I have this:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile project(':AppData:Local:Android:sdk:extras:google:google_play_services:libproject:google-play-services_lib')
}
```

it seems like I have to add a library to the project path,but I don't know which one and neither where is it. So, what things should I see to fix it? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're attempting to add Google Play Services as a dependency to your Gradle-based Android app. I'd like to suggest to just follow the [instructions provided by Google](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup):

If you want to add the full Play Services library as dependency, then add:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
```

Alternatively, you can also selectively add the submodules/APIs relevant to your app. I.e. if all you need is Google Maps, the that would be:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
```

A full list of all individual submodules/APIs can be found on that same instructions page.

Answer (score 0):

To add Google Play services to an app see the following documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)